# Android custom control with translate animation

Tags: android, animation, xamarin

I'm pretty new in the android world.

I try to create in my app a custom control like the following description:
 - Objects appears one by one (timer) at the right of that custom controls and are translated (with animation) to the left of the screen.

The rendering is the following right now:

[image: Staf]

And the code is like:

```
public abstract class SheetBase : SurfaceView
{

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        this.Update(canvas);
    }
}

public class MusicSheet : SheetBase, ISurfaceHolderCallback
{
    public MusicSheet(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public MusicSheet(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public MusicSheet(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public MusicSheet(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    public MusicSheet(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(Canvas canvas)
    {
    // Logic to draw staf on Canvas
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, Format format, int width, int height)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        this._thread = new Thread(this.Loop);
        this._thread.Start();
    }

    public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        this._thread?.Abort();
    }

    private void Loop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Canvas c = null;
            try
            {
                c = this.Holder.LockCanvas();
                c.DrawColor(Color.Transparent, PorterDuff.Mode.Clear);
                // Draw content at the new position
            }
            finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                    this.Holder.UnlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about the solution / performances ?

Comment: Provide some sort of code, what you have achieved so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewPropertyAnimator` to translate a `View`.

For example,

```
view.animate()
    .translationX(100) // horizontal translation
    .translationY(100) // vertical translation
```

To animate from right to left:

```
view.animate()
    .translationX( - screenWidth )
```

Refer the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for more info.